# calculating the efficiency of a microwave oven

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, energy-efficiency, radiation, thermal-radiation

If I want to calculate the efficiency of a microwave oven, I have the input Energy (= power (watts) x time (s)) and the output which I measured using temperature difference (q=mct). 
So do I divide output/input x 100 or do I find the difference between them (=work) then divide it by the input energy?

Comment: Make sure your units balance on both sides...

Comment: yes they do                                                                                                              input energy: microwave is 650W and I'm heating for 20 seconds, so 650W x 20s = 13000J                                                                                                                              output energy: experimental value of 7698.56J

Comment: so to calc effieicny do I just divide the 2 then x 100? or do I need to find the difference between them then divide by the input energy?

Answer (score 1):

The equation for efficiency in thermodynamics is as follows:

$$\eta = W_{out}/W_{in}$$

and to get this as a percentage you just multiply $\eta \;\mathrm{x}100=\%$

See the link below!
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_ef

Comment: it says its work out / Q in, not work in

Comment: so in my case... if u read the question, I calculated the energy in using the microwaves power and I calculated the energy in using q=mct... so what do I use???///////

Comment: You should be able to apply the answer to your situation.... How about "efficiency = Useful Output / Total input"

Comment: I'm agree with @SolarMike, his/her definition is more accurate, the useful output is the temperature of the food, but the inside and the food container (plates or...) also the magnetic losses in transformer is not negligible, and you didn't take the effect of reactive power into account, since the microwave can be indicative. I'm sure the apparent power gives you more accurate results, in case of capacitive microwave the active power is a good estimation.

Comment: @Shahad The link actually says efficiency = benefit / cost.... before you get down to Q or W...

Comment: @Shahad - In the section on heat engines it says work out / heat in, but in the section on energy conversion it says Q out / Q in.  As noted by others, the key is that you divide the useful output by the total input.